# PHP Syntax Error Help for a Database Search Page

Tags: php, html

When I run this PHP page on my web server it does not display correctly around the search button & text box area.

PHP is not my speciality so if someone could please cast their skilled eyes over this for me and tell me where the error(s) are, this would be a great help.

Thank you in advance...

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body vlink="#0000FF" alink="#0000FF"> 
<? include 'vars.php'; ?> 
<? include 'searchfunct.php'; ?> 
<table width="500" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"   bgcolor="#66FFCC"> 
<tr> 
<td> <p align="center"> <font face="Arial"><a href="search.php">Search</a></font></p> 
  <form action="search.php" method="get"> 
    <div align="center"><font face="Arial"> 
      <input maxLength="100" size="60" value**="<?= htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_GET["search"])); ?>" name="search">** 
      <input type="submit" value="Search" > 
      </p> 
      </font> </div> 
  </form></td> 
</tr> 
</table> 
<div align="left"> 
<?
$search=stripslashes($_GET["search"]);
$page=$_GET["page"];
if($search!="")
fSearch($search,$page,$server,$user,$pass,$database,$Logging,$ResultsPerPage);
?> 
</div> 
<br>
<br>
<div style="color:#CCCCCC; text-align:center;">Developed By Stefano Alimonti And  Stefano Fantin</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: stripslashes? if your php install has magic_quotes turned on, you really need to update the php install.

Comment: are you trying to bold code with `**`..?? i hope they are not a part of your code..

Comment: Thanks for this Marc striplashes was removed from PHP in later versions which I am using. Is there an altenitive way to avoid using striplashes or rolling back my PHP version?

Comment: Sorry that was just from when I was typing the post up on here, I thought it did nothing when I tried bolding the problem code, evidently not.

Comment: The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: `@peter` or `@PeterSmith` will both work..you can find such information by clicking help next to where you are typing a comment..if you won't use this notation then people whom you want to address won't be able to hear your voice..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `<? and <?=` is deprecated in php's latest version I have replaced it with `"<?php"` and `"<?php echo"`

Updated html would be

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body vlink="#0000FF" alink="#0000FF"> 
<?php include 'vars.php'; ?> 
<?php include 'searchfunct.php'; ?> 
<table width="500" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"   bgcolor="#66FFCC"> 
<tr> 
<td> <p align="center"> <font face="Arial"><a href="search.php">Search</a></font></p> 
  <form action="search.php" method="get"> 
    <div align="center"><font face="Arial"> 
      <input maxLength="100" size="60" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_GET["search"])); ?>" name="search">** 
      <input type="submit" value="Search" > 
      </p> 
      </font> </div> 
  </form></td> 
</tr> 
</table> 
<div align="left"> 
<?php
$search=stripslashes($_GET["search"]);
$page=$_GET["page"];
if($search!="")
   fSearch($search,$page,$server,$user,$pass,$database,$Logging,$ResultsPerPage);
?> 
</div> 
<br>
<br>
<div style="color:#CCCCCC; text-align:center;">Developed By Stefano Alimonti And  Stefano Fantin</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

if it still gives error post the exact error in comment

Comment: I now have this error: `parse error syntax error unexpected ' ' in php on line 160`

Comment: The error is in another PHP file searchfuct.php - I shall dig it.

Comment: The line with the error is this: `mysql_close($connection);` to me this looks ok.

Comment: yes this like seems ok, my be it is in other file which you may have included, have you tried something else

Answer (score 1):

it can be an issue  with php short tags being disabled

You can replace  `<?=` with `<?php echo`

and `<?` with `<?php`

Comment: if that were the case, then you've missed the obvious `<?` all over the script.

Answer (score 0):

This markup doesn't look right:

```
<input maxLength="100" size="60" value**="<?= htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_GET["search"])); ?>" name="search">**
```

Try:

```
<input maxLength="100" size="60" value="**<?php htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_GET['search'])); ?>**" name="search">
```